# When to use Blend for a WPF developer?

Tags: wpf, blend

I'm a WPF developer and use VS Pro 2012 everyday for UI adjusting and coding. I installed Blend for Visual Studio but I never used it (just launched it by accident several times).

I'm afraid that I missed something by not using Blend. If I did miss something, what is it then?

Answer (score 1):

Blend lets you design WPF UI, create controls and determine their behaviors visually (by UI), and Visual studio lets you do that programatically.

There is nothing you can do in blend, that you can't do in visual studio.

It is a tool for people who are less comfortable using code, and more comfortable using a cool UI to create custom controls and behaviors and design thier UI

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2012 and later, the WPF UI designer *is* Blend; it's actually loaded in the background and accessed through out-of-process COM interfaces. This is part of the reason its behavior can be a bit bizarre at times, why you get messages about being able to edit the XAML while the design surface is loading.

If you're used to VS form builders you're going to be fine with Visual Studio.